# queryURL with swift does not work while it works with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, url, nsstring

I need to work with some queryURL with Swift. I am new to Swift. While I did this job with Objective C once, and it worked correctly with Objective C.

Here is the code for my Objective C project which it works correctly:

```
NSString* queryURL;

queryURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://google.com];
    

NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];

NSString *result = [queryURL stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];

NSURL *googleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:result];

NSError *error;

NSString *googlePage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:googleURL

                                                encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding

                                                   error:&error];


   NSLog(@"Back%@", googlePage);
```

and as I said, it works fine. Now I change this to below code in Swift:

```
   if let url = URL(string: "https://google.com") {

    do {

        let contents = try String(contentsOf: url)

        print(contents)

    } catch {

        // contents could not be loaded

    }

} else {

    // the URL was bad!

}
```

but it confronts an Error `contents could not be loaded`. What can I try next?

Comment: Swift got more disciplined about cleaning up the responsibilities of the various standard library types. It's not sensible for an `NSString` to be responsible for loading itself from a URL. Imagine what would happen if `String` was responsible for being able to load itself from anywhere a string might be loadable from. Databases, file systems, YAML/JSON/CSV/XML, etc. It would bloat massively. Instead, in Swift, you would use `URLSession`. That also solves a second problem: this ObjC code is synchronous, and makes the whole program wait on a network call. That's never a good use experience.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you very much , seems very helpful information. can you answer the question ? and if possible please tell me what is your suggestion to do it? thank you

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_from_websites?language=objc

Answer (score 1):

You left out the encoding in swift (the parameter is optional in swift but required in objc): `let contents = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .ascii)`